# Selenium, Webdriver is overloading memory

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, memory, webdriver

I need to open tabs and collect data and close tabs. About 600 tabs.

The problem is that the Chrome driver overloads memory with each new tab. Even if you close using `driver.close()`, the memory used is almost not reduced. `driver.quit()` will terminate the session, so I'm not using it. I tracked Chrome overload in the task manager, the problem is not in the collected data, but in opening new tabs.

Why is memory used even after closing tabs and how to deal with it?

P.S. The site and the code just for example opens and closes tabs

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
url = 'https://edition.cnn.com/'

driver.get(url)
for i in range(25):
    time.sleep(0.5)
    driver.execute_script("window.open();")
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[-1])
    driver.get(url)
    driver.close()
    driver.switch_to.window(driver.window_handles[0])
```

Comment: Not sure if you can do much. Could you try clearing the chrome's cache ? https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/#method-clearBrowserCache

Comment: @iFlo Browser cache is not the same as memory.

Answer (score 0):

It's a known issue that Selenium WebDriver is experiencing memory overload when you open and close several tabs. Every opened tab uses more memory, and although while Selenium's 'driver.close()' technique is meant to close the tab, it doesn't necessarily release all of the memory resources that go along with it. Over time, this may cause RAM bloat, particularly when managing numerous tabs.

You can do this by quitting the WebDriver instance (driver.quit()) and creating a new one at regular intervals.